# MQTT Request Token

Tags: java, request, response, mqtt

We are using MQTT to deliver messages from our server to an android device.

Is it possible to receive an exact response to the request?
I already had an idea to enter a query-response log. Will this help?

Now I just have this situation. The user wants to get information about the device. A message is sent via MQTT and everything is lost on this. You have to do the second in the query in the log of the devices and from there already get the necessary information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MQTT v3 does not natively support request/response style messaging. You can implement it, but you have to add request ids to the message payload to signify that a message is a response to a specific request message.

MQTT v5 has native support for request/response style messaging, you can find detail in the spec [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/csprd01/mqtt-v5.0-csprd01.html#_Toc489530272). MQTT v5 is a new version of the spec and as of January 2018 not many brokers or clients have been updated to support all the new features yet.